# Get the url of link clicked when router deactivate event is fired

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it possible to pass the URL of the route which is clicked when router deactivate event is fired?
I have the deactivate gaurd something like this

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate}  from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }    from 'rxjs/Observable';
export interface CanComponentDeactivate {
 canDeactivate: () => Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
@Injectable()
export class CanDeactivateGuard implements CanDeactivate<CanComponentDeactivate> {
constructor(public activeroute:ActivatedRoute){

}
canDeactivate(component: CanComponentDeactivate) {
return component.canDeactivate ? component.canDeactivate(URL) : true;
}
}
```

And the deactivate event in my component as below

    `canDeactivate(Url:any) {
      console.log(Url);
      return false;
    }`

I have made a plunker demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/0zLwIoUK7hxm5qZWzsye?p=preview where i am able to get the url of link clicked but it is showing type errors like `Property _futureSnapShot Doesnot exist on type ActivatedRoute`.Is there any good practices to get the url of the route which is clicked when router deactivate event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `router.events` by injecting `router: Router` in the constructor.

```
router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(val);         
});
```

`val` will include the url of the route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have updated the demo http://plnkr.co/edit/0zLwIoUK7hxm5qZWzsye?p=preview by injecting the router event and passed the url when deactivate event is fired but for the first time i get the value as undefined when deactivate event is fired.Steps to follow:Click on crisis center link and then on heroes.Open the console window you will find the value that is passed

Comment: I have forked your plunker demo (http://plnkr.co/edit/BGrfAa5CQanfFKcmhgf6?p=preview)

Comment: I made some changes: 1) added app/route.service.ts wherein the url is saved, 2) app.component.ts added injected RouteService to save the url on each route change, 3) RouteService injected in CanDeactivateGuard to read the url. Because route.events.subscribe is a async function it can take some milliseconds to set the URL and therefore it can occure that when reading the url in CanDeactivate is undefined. In that case set a timeout or somthing similar to wait for until the url is defined.

Comment: also Currently CanDeactivate is not firing because I don't know when to call it.